# What would be the hardest material in the universe

Tags: condensed-matter

I wonder to ask what is the potentially **hardest**, most solid, man-known material in the universe.

I search for the most unbreakable material in the univirse. Resistant to heating included.
I've heard that Pulsar's surface is thousands of times more solid than the diamond for instance but I am not so sure how unbreakable it is.

Comment: Katchin - http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Katchin

Comment: @JohnDoe perhaps funny  .

Comment: You need to be more specific. First of all, do you really mean to ask for the *hardest* material? Or the strongest? (They're two very different things). In either case, there are various different types of hardness and strength...

Comment: Can't I ask about both ? Okay then I will choose the one of most importance.

Comment: The most unbreakable materials? That's liquids and gases. They can never break. Electromagnetic fields are good, too.

Comment: The surface of a neutron star is not particularly incompressible. It depends on your definition of hardness.

Comment: @RobJeffries Yes, the surface of a neutron star is immensely solid, therefore it is heavy. But that doesn't mean it is unbreakable. Not in any manner so I suspected it might not be the answer.  And the worst might be that it doesn't even have a name. Other unbreakable solid material resistant to pressure, heating and other destructible forces...

Comment: @CuriousOne It's a fairly good point, but I think it is clear that it is about solid materials. Otherwise I wouldn't talk about pulsar's surfaces and it wouldn't be about being "unbreakable", but decaying and a whole lot other processes.

Comment: A pulsar surface "breaks" all the time. Those things have "earthquakes".

Comment: @CuriousOne Yes. A sad story, but yes.

Comment: @CuriousOne If I ask , "For a given shape and size (preferably cylindrical or spherical), a solid of what material at STP is most resistant to bending, breaking, deformation and abrasion under applied force ?", what will the answer be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the hardest material known to exist in the universe must be the neutron matter, the stuff, of which neutron stars are made. It is so dense though that it cannot exist on earth, as it would just drop through the floor and through the ground to the center of earth. So more realistically, here on earth, different materials can be hardest or strongest or most unbreakable depending on the type of impact. Diamond of course is one of the hardest, but can be broken. Spider fiber is one of the strongest to tear. There is a new material that also in some ways is the strongest ever, graphene, check it out!

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphene

Comment: Neutron matter is a fluid

Comment: @Thomas: A "fluid" in what sense? Under that pressure a diamond would be a gas. A "fluid" is simply a scientific talk that means no crystal lattice. Still the denclsiest and strongest material possible that will vaporize anything on its way.

Comment: In the usual sense. A solid is rigid and has non-zero elastic moduli. A fluid is not rigid, it does not have elastic moduli. It satisfies the equations of fluid dynamics, and is characterized by a non-zero shear viscosity.

Comment: The surface of a neutron star is a Coulomb solid (called the neutron star crust), made of positively charged nuclei embedded in a gas of electrons (and some neutrons). This solid is a candidate for the hardest solid in nature. There are some estimates for elastic moduli and breaking stress.

Comment: See here https://arxiv.org/abs/1006.2279

Comment: @Thomas: I see, so mountains on a neutron star would only last for a few years, but if we make a mountain made of diamond and put it on a neutron star, it wouldn't last one second. Great.

Comment: @safesphere  If I ask the question this way, "For a given shape and size (preferably rod or ball shaped), a solid of what material at STP is most resistant to bending, breaking, deformation and abrasion?", what will the answer be?

Comment: @Aurelius Diamond always comes to mind as a good candidate, but you can’t make a rod or ball out of diamond. Some other technological materials exist of a similar (or even slightly higher) strength, which are much easier to shape than diamond. You may get more info if you post this as a question rather than a comment.

Comment: @safesphere If I do post a question, will it be closed for being a duplicate of this one?

Comment: @Aurelius Not of this one, cause you’d specify STP, but it may be closed for some other reason. Don’t be discouraged if this happens. Just see what the reason for closing is and post again with an improved verbiage. At the minimum you will be pointed to a similar question with the answer you are looking for.